# How to properly lazyload component in angular?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-load-children

I am stuck with some simple route management in Angular :
I have this first module :

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
> import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
> import { LayoutComponent } from './ui/components/layout/layout.component';
>
>
> const routes: Routes = [{ path: '**',
>      component: LayoutComponent,
>      children: [    { path: '', redirectTo: '/posts', pathMatch: 'full'},
>     { path: 'posts',loadChildren: './posts/posts.module#PostsModule' }] }];
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
>      ],
>   exports: [RouterModule]
> })
> export class AppRoutingModule { }
> ```

And the "PostModule" which should show simple "it works" component :

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';\n
> import { Routes } from '@angular/router';\n
> import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
> import { PostsComponent } from './containers/posts/posts.component';
> import { ProfileComponent } from './containers/profile/profile.component';
>
> const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: PostsComponent },{ path: ':profileId', component: ProfileComponent },];
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
>   exports: [RouterModule]
> })
> export class PostsRoutingModule { }
> ```

But none of the route

> http://localhost:4200/posts/
>
> http://localhost:4200/posts/1

show the expected content

I suppose I have miss something simple my app.component look like this:

> ```
>    <router-outlet>
>       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
>    </router-outlet>
> ```

I have read some poste on "lazy loading", but what I wrote seem coherent from  what I learned until now, where is the mistake ?

Comment: Could you post your postModule.ts class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the way you structured the routings. It should be configured like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'posts', loadChildren: './posts/posts.module#PostsModule' }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

The idea of "path: '**'" is to handle any non-defined route you entered in the browser (i.e. /hello-world) and redirects to the root or any other defined route you choose.

So in the way you have it defined, the routing is always capturing the navigation and showing the LayoutComponent.

Comment: you've nailed it !

Answer (score 1):

Which Angular version are you using? Have you tried the following?

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '**',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/posts', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'posts', loadChildren : () => import('./posts/posts.module').then(x => x.PostsModule) }
  ]
}];
```

**Update:**

The component added to a router outlet by the router is added below the outer `router-outlet`, therefore adding something inside the  is pointless.

The inner `router-outlet` needs to be moved into `LayoutComponent` component, which is added to  by the router.

Answer (score 0):

First try to do the following:

```
   <router-outlet>
      <p>Layout Component loaded</p>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </router-outlet>
```

Then, if something is written in your landing page, put the second router-outlet in your LayoutComponent.

In order to use multiple outlets side by side in one template, you need to use named router outlets.

Comment: I just mentioned it in case he needs for some reason to use it side by side.

Comment: Yes having a nested router outlet is pointless (it seems that we should avoid even space inside ?), you always will have the most inner router-outlet use, I have been using this just as I read  an answer like this somewhere on this site....

Comment: Nah, space won't do anything bad.